# Excel - Data Validation Override

Tags: excel, vba, validation

I'm working on a project for our fabrication warehouse. Currently, we have a system where the workers will type in what order they are working on their tablets and then the part numbers, dimensions, etc will all autofill based on a query of all currently open manufacturing orders...

Whenever we have a prototype or expedited part it won't show up in the query. I was wondering if anyone knew some VBA code (or simpler solutions) that would allow us to keep the current data validation but also give operators an option to override.

Example series of events:

1- operator receives and types in order number

2- msgbox pops up saying "this doesn't exist --- is this a prototype or expedited part?" (answer Y/N)

3- Override message pops up "are you sure xxxx is the correct part number" (operator selects yes)

4- data gets inputed as usual but requires manual entries for dimensions, parts used, etc.

psuedo code:

steps 1-3 : a series of if statements and message boxes guiding the decisions is not too difficult

step 4: where im getting tripped up... how would i unlock that row so they could have custom input for that order and then lock it again once they are finished.

Comment: It might be safer to give them a userform to enter the information - then you can add it to the row programmatically (with protect/unprotect) without worrying about them manually "finishing" the entry

Comment: Definitely! We are probably going to move this direction in whatever the final version of the project looks like. Permissions, edits, access and such all seem simpler using user forms. Thank you for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion.
What if you add a non-protected column to the file (assuming that each row is a new entry and entry details are stored in columns).
So, one column with data validation and a warning with the text you mentioned.
And another column to enter the order number manually.

Comment: This is a good work around idea. I'll give this a try and play around with hiding/unhiding columns so that functionality and UI stay the same. Thank you!